# Django REST Framework - Caching Embedded objects in viewset response

Tags: python, django, caching, redis, django-rest-framework

I've been caching `list` and `retrieve` methods for ViewSets in Django REST Framework using drf-extensions https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#caching.

I wrote a modification to cache the key indefinitely for those `list` and `retrieve` methods which invalidates the keys for these methods when an object is modified.

The issue I am trying to solve is cache invalidation when an embedded object is modified. I am not familiar with the typical patterns for cache invalidation for embedded objects.

**Ex:**

```
{
    "id": 1, 
    "position": "manager",
    "company": "Google",
    "user": {
        "id": 1, 
        "email": "johnsmith@example.com", 
        "first_name": "John", 
        "last_name": "Doe", 
        "last_login": "2015-01-05T20:46:15.400Z", 
        "joined_at": "2014-12-10T19:54:45.588Z", 
    }
}
```

A user modifies the user object, ideally the cache key set for the `list` and `retrieve` methods for the user ViewSet along with the embedded object ViewSet should both be invalidated.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you currently invalidate the viewset?

Comment: On model save and delete it sends a signal to find keys using redis' `redis.keys()` method prefixed with the model name ending in `list` and `retrieve` and then the associated primary key of the model in the case of `retrieve`

So my keys look something like:
`User.UserViewSet.list`
`User.UserViewSet.retrieve.1`

Comment: You could basically invalidate all UserViewSets when a User is saved, since checking which one it belongs to would be complex (or, store their relationships which could be wasteful as heck).

Comment: Maybe it's best not to only write to these objects through the parent object so both are updated. Or In the case of non reverse foreign key relationships I can coerce the invalidation of the foreign key's `list` and `retrieve`

Comment: That makes sense. Is non-cached performance a big concern?

Comment: I was afraid of perfoming too many database fetches or creating too many database connections as I recently had an issue where there were zombie connections and I was getting a lot of request timeouts on heroku, they were from a different endpoint taking too long I think. But I was planning to cache all of the endpoints, but perhaps in this case this is early optimization.

I have added connection pooling as well since Django doesn't support it out of the box. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-concurrency-and-database-connections